# LoadBitmap returns NULL after program has been running for a while

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I am working on a program that has bmp images that reflect the status of a system (therefore, these lights can change depending on the status). These images are located on the main window, and next to them is a tab window with a couple of tabs. When I first run my program, everything works great. I can change tabs and the images still to the right of them, correctly reflecting the status. I left my program running over night, and found that when I came back, the program will still be running correctly (all my buttons and tabs work) but my images disappeared.

I debugged my `WM_PAINT`, and noticed that this code

```
Light = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(LightSource[i]));
```

Now returns `NULL`.

So my question is, how can I make this work properly all the time? Any ideas?

```
int LightSource[12] = { IDB_BITMAP1, IDB_BITMAP1, IDB_BITMAP1, IDB_BITMAP1, IDB_BITMAP1, IDB_BITMAP1, IDB_BITMAP1, IDB_BITMAP1, IDB_BITMAP1, IDB_BITMAP1, IDB_BITMAP1, IDB_BITMAP1 };

case WM_PAINT:
    {
        HBITMAP Light = NULL;   //Bitmaps for the light indications
        //Prepares for painting window
         hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        //Retrieves the coordinates of the windows client area
         GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        //creates a copy of the memory device context 
        HDC hdcDouble = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP bmOld;

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)    //For all indicator lights
        {
            Light = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(LightSource[i]));         //Get a bitmap of the picture to be updated
            bmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcDouble, Light);                                    //Get a handle to the image being replaced
            BitBlt(hdc, xLight[i], yLight[i], rc.right, rc.bottom, hdcDouble, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);   //Bit block transfer of the bitmap color data
        }

        SelectObject(hdcDouble, bmOld);
        DeleteDC(hdcDouble);
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        //Set some window text, no need to show

        DeleteObject(Light);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: You have a loop calling LoadBitmap 12 times but there's only 1 DeleteObject, maybe that causes problems? Start with checking error codes, and consider moving the LoadBitmap out of the loop and do it just once at application start

Comment: Well there's only one DeleteObject because I only created one HBITMAP Light and used that variable Light to load all 12 images. I guess I could make Light an array and load the images to a specific index of Light array, it couldnt hurt but I dont know how it would make a difference.

Also, if I use LoadBitmap only once at the start, how would I be able to change the lights to reflect the status? Different bitmaps are loaded depending on the status, so I thought I would need to call LoadBitmap to load the different status lights

Comment: You load a bitmap.  This uses some memory.  You go round the loop.  You load another bitmap.  It uses some more memory.  You repeat this twelve times and you exit the loop.  You then delete the last bitmap.  What about the other eleven?

Comment: Ohhh right, I understand now

Comment: You should probably only load Light once for your entire program somewhere else and use that one instance in your `WM_PAINT` rather than trying to load the bitmap each message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the question so it doesn't stay open: Since you are not freeing the bitmaps, it looks like you have a resource leak in your program. Free the bitmaps after using them.